# PHP MySQL второй вопрос не видит переменной, которая есть в первом вопросе

Tags: php, mysql

с помощью вопроса: ↓

```
    $sql_id = "SELECT id FROM wiadomosci ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
    $result = $conn->query($sql_id);
    
        while ($row2 = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo $row2["id"];
        }
```

я получаю последнее `id` из моей таблицы, и так как я его вывожу в цикле `while`:
`echo $row2["id"];`,то действительно вижу что это нужная мне цифра, и у меня есть еще
следующий вопрос: ↓

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM wiadomosci WHERE wlasciciel='$wlasciciel' AND
            katalog='Odebrane' AND id > '{$row2["id"]}' ORDER BY data";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        $i = 0;
        while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
            $ms[$i] = $row;
            $i++;
        }
     echo json_encode($ms);
} else {
    echo "brak";
}
```

В этом вопросе я пытаюсь использовать выше найденное мной последнее `id` тоесть`$row2["id"]`
Но в консоле получаю следующее: **Trying to access array offset on value of type null in (и здесь

строка со вторым вопросом в которой есть `$row2["id"]`**)
Я так понимаю что проблема в том что оно просто не видит `$row2["id"]` или может я не понимаю
и проблема здесь в чем то другом? Буду рад за любые подсказки!

Comment: Нужен полный код. В приведенных кусках проблема может быть только в том, что вы обращаетесь к `$row2["id"]` в разных условиях, и во втором случае `$row2` вообще не инициирован.

Comment: У меня в этом файле и есть только этот код, то есть эти два вопроса